# windbg: Command output to text file

Tags: windbg

How can I Save Output of a command in WinDbg to a Text File?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Start WinDbg from the command line using the -logo option:

```
windbg.exe -logo logfile.txt
```

That will get everything done logged to the file specified. You can find more details of the command line options [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh451024(v=vs.85).aspx).

Or, if you are already in a debugging session, you can use the .logopen command to start logging. For more info on this command see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff564018(v=vs.85).aspx)

Or you can click edit->Open/Close log file in the WinDbg GUI.

More info on log files is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh451024.aspx).

Answer (score 32):

You can use .logopen , all of the commands you input and response from windbg will be logged, and then use .logclose to flush the data into

Answer (score 16):

You can also do this from the WinDbg gui 'Edit>Write Window Text To File...' if you find that easier.

Answer (score 0):

To send the **output of a specific command** to a file, go and get [Tee](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/unixports.php#TEE), (I use  Tee.bat), put it into a directory covered by the Windows `PATH` environment variable (or [add the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho) you've put it in). Then use the following syntax from the WinDbg GUI to send the output of a command to a file

```
.shell -ci "<command>" tee <file>

.shell -ci "!gcroot 000002b56c414750" tee c:\path\out_01.log
```

There's an undocumented `!!` abbreviation of `.shell`. So you could just do:

```
!! -ci "!gcroot 000002b56c414750" tee c:\path\out_01.log
```

**Background**

You can run [shell commands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/using-shell-commands) in the WinDbg GUI. The [syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-shell--command-shell-) is:

```
.shell [Options] [ShellCommand] 
.shell -i InFile [-o OutFile [-e ErrFile]] [Options] ShellCommand
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42986481/windbg-command-output-to-clipboard) I found the solution to send the command output to the clipboard.

```
.shell -ci "<command>" clip
```

If you can send the output to `clip`, shouldn't it be possible to send it to a file, like so?

```
.shell -ci "<command>" > <file>
.shell -ci "!gcroot 000002b56c414750" > c:\path\out_01.log
```

Would be nice, but it **does not work**. In the [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-shell--command-shell-#remarks) I found this example.

```
.shell -ci "!process 0 7" perl.exe parsemyoutput.pl
```

So it is possible to send the output to an application. Just like the above example using `clip`. And that's where [Tee](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/unixports.php#TEE) came in. But you could use any other script or .exe which takes the output and stores it in a file or another place.