# WinDbg command output to clipboard

Tags: debugging, windbg

Is there any way to redirect a command output to clipboard in WinDbg similar to

```
<command> | clip
```

Comment: Not aware of a way to do this. Closed you could get would be to use .logopen/.logappend/.logclose to save to file and paste from there

Comment: Not tried it but I imagine that using `cdb` might work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows 10, `clip` is a built-in Windows command line executable to copy text into the clipboard. On other versions of Windows you might need to find a similar tool and install it somewhere in `%PATH%`.

You can use it from WinDbg with

```
.shell -ci "<command>" clip
```

e.g.

```
.shell -ci "k" clip
```

to copy the call stack to the clipboard.

There's also the undocumented `!!` abbreviation of `.shell`, so you can do

```
 !! -ci "k" clip
```

If you use a WinDbg startup script anyway, you can define an alias, e.g.

```
as | .shell -ci
```

and then do a very short

```
| "k" clip
```

Note that this redefines `|`, which shows the current process. I use that command at least once in every debugging session, so I don't recommend that. Maybe you find a better shortcut.

Comment: Omg! This is awesome! Thank you so much @Thomas ! :D