# How to add a folder to `Path` environment variable in Windows 10 (with screenshots)

Tags: path, windows-10, environment-variables

On StackOverflow and on the net in general, there are outdated and few guides on how to add a specific folder to the Windows 10 `Path` environment variable of the user.

I think a complete guide for new developers with step by step instructions and screenshots could be really usefull to help them executing utilities from a [Command Prompt](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b3/Command_Prompt_on_Windows_10_RTM.png) without the need of the full path, simplifying the things.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

For the guide below we want to add an example utility called `mytool.exe` which is located in `C:\Users\NewFolderInPath\mytool.exe`, so that everytime i want to execute the mytool utility i don't have to specify the full path.

I used this as an example, you can replace the folder with something more realistic like the JDK bin directory located here `C:\Program Files\Java\{JDK_VERSION}\bin` to execute `javac`, `keytool` or everything you want.

> **Step 1** - Click on the `Windows` icon

[image]

> **Step 2** - Click on the `Settings` icon

[image]

> **Step 3** - Click on `System`

[image]

> **Step 4** - Click on `About`

[image]

> **Step 5** - Click on `System info`

[image]

> **Step 6** - Click on `Advanced system settings`

[image]

> **Step 7** - Click on `Environment variables...`

[image]

> **Step 8** - Select `Path` row and then click `Edit`

[image]

> **Step 9** - Click `New` and then click `Browse`, then in the next panel which will open you need to select the folder you want in the `Path`. For the initial premise of this guide i will add the folder `C:\Users\NewFolderInPath`

[image]

> **Step 10** - Click `OK` and click every `OK` button you will encounter to close every previous windows.

[image]

> **Step 11** - Open a `command prompt (cmd)` and now you can execute your utility without specifying the full path.

[image]

Comment: In addition to this walkthrough this video was helpful - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=extCL1UU5wk and so was this one https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gBHOeI5QB8M in understanding what test command to try and that it wont work until you close out of command prompt and reopen it (looks like I have keytool running now :)

Comment: tip - just type 'env' in the start menu - select 'edit environment variables' top item to skip half these steps

Comment: If you type 'environment' into the start menu it also gives you the option for whether to edit variables for the current user of the system. The instructions above require admin privileges so for me end up editing the admin account's path instead of my regular user's account (my company's IT dept are sadists so I have multiple accounts).

Answer (score 16):

## DOS - A historical answer

For older systems, this is the way it was done and if you're working in in some flavor of Dos this is the easiest answer:

**To print each entry of Windows PATH variable on a new line, execute:**

`C:\> echo %PATH:;=&echo.%`

**Set Windows PATH variable for the current session:**

`C:\> set PATH=%PATH%;C:\path\to\directory\`

**Set Windows PATH Permanently**

Run as Administrator: The setx command is only available starting from Windows 7 and requires elevated command prompt.

Permanently add a directory to the user PATH variable:

`C:\> setx path "%PATH%;C:\path\to\directory\"`

Permanently add a directory to the system PATH variable (for all users):

`C:\> setx /M path "%PATH%;C:\path\to\directory\"`

## PowerShell - To avoid problems on modern systems

On modern Windows there are more modern tools you can use to avoid some pitfalls that come with modern implementations of how the %PATH% variable is used.

What used to be user settings vs. system settings is now referred to as user vs machine settings. They are the same. User settings can be modified by anyone and only affects their own environment. Modification of Machine level settings require administrator privileges because they apply to all users.

**To print each entry of Windows PATH variable on a new line, execute:**

`[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "User").Split(";")`

`[Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "Machine").Split(";")`

**Set Windows PATH avoiding the pitfalls of setx method**

The two main things we want to avoid are the character limit of 1024 and duplicate entries. Using the modern `SetEnvironmentVariable` will avoid the 1024 character limit so we could do a simple thing:

```
function Add-Path-User($newPath) {
    $Path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "User") + [IO.Path]::PathSeparator + $newPath
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "Path", $Path, "User" )
}

function Add-Path-Machine($newPath) {
    $Path = [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "Machine") + [IO.Path]::PathSeparator + $newPath
    [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable( "Path", $Path, "Machine" )
}
```

But if you want to avoid duplicates you would need something more involved:

```
Function Set-PathVariable {
    param (
        [string]$AddPath,
        [ValidateSet('Process', 'User', 'Machine')]
        [string]$Scope = 'Process'
    )

    $regexPaths = @()
    if ($PSBoundParameters.Keys -contains 'AddPath') {
        $regexPaths += [regex]::Escape($AddPath)
    }
    
    $arrPath = [System.Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $Scope).Split([IO.Path]::PathSeparator)
    foreach ($path in $regexPaths) {
        $arrPath = $arrPath | Where-Object { $_ -notMatch "^$path\\?$" }
    }

    $value = ($arrPath + $addPath).Join([IO.Path]::PathSeparator)
    [System.Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('PATH', $value, $Scope)
}
```

Comment: The `echo` trick is neat, but note that `setx.exe` is best avoided for persistent updates to the `Path` environment variables: while it _may_ have no (immediate) ill effects, it _can_:
`setx.exe` has a hard 1024-character limit, and replaces the original `REG_EXPAND_SZ` value with a `REG_SZ` value if the new value happens not to contain _unexpanded_ environment-variable references. Additionally, you're _duplicating_ entries by basing your new value on the process-level value of `%PATH%`, which is a _composite_ of the system-level and user-level definition and only contains _expanded_ values.

Comment: It is an absolute __NO GO - NEVER EVER__ using the command `setx` with __local__ `PATH` value referenced with `%PATH%` to update persistent stored __user__ or __system__ environment variable `PATH`. That corrupts the __user/system__ `PATH` value by creating duplicate folder paths, expanding environment variable references which could result in a program not working anymore, and truncation of `PATH` value to 1024 characters which means with loosing folder paths. Nobody should ever use the last two command lines.

Comment: [Why are other folder paths also added to system PATH with SetX and not only the specified folder path?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25919222/3074564) and [What is the best practice for adding a directory to the PATH environment variable on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77422401/3074564) These two answers offer more information why a modification of persistent stored __user__ or __system__ environment variable `PATH` should be best done never from the command line but by using the __Environment Variables__ system configuration dialog window of Windows.

Comment: While I appreciate the nuance you have brought to the discussion I do feel your solution is over-engineered. It should be noted that the `PATH=%PATH%` pattern has been the industry standard since the 1980's. I have personally used this pattern that long, starting with DOS 3. I have never run into the issues you raise. They do appear to be modern problems requiring modern solutions. So while your solution is cool for the edge case it protects against, I cannot agree with NEVER EVER.

Comment: @HackSlash It is absolutely no problem and indeed industry standard to modify __local__ environment variable `PATH` of a running process. It is 100% okay using `set "PATH=%PATH%;C:\OneMoreFolderPath"` or `set "PATH=C:\One more folder path;%PATH%"` or the command __PATH__ for doing the same in a command prompt window or a batch file for __local__ `PATH`. But the modification of persistent stored __user__ or __system__ environment variable `PATH` with `setx` and usage of __local__ `PATH` value referenced with `%PATH%` is a __NO GO - NEVER EVER__ although posted unfortunately on many web pages.