# OpenJDK8 for windows

Tags: java

Im a bit confused about how to download openjdk8 for windows.

If I go to http://openjdk.java.net/install/ then under JDK 8 there are only two sections: "Debian, Ubuntu, etc." and "Fedora, Oracle Linux, Red Hat Enterprise Linux, etc.". Where is windows?

Comment: http://jdk.java.net/8/

Comment: http://adoptopenjdk.net/

Comment: @bobah But, how can i tell the difference between openjdk and the regular commercial jdk? On the download link jdk.java.net/8 it isnt explicitly stated that its openjdk. Also if i install it and run java -version i cant find anything stating that its openjdk.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you care to install OpenJDK on Windows? Oracle JDK 8 is free to use. It’s just not open/free software.

Comment: Exactly, not free (especially from next yaer) :)

Comment: Oracle will charge for the use of JDK in 2019. That's the reason why we have to move to Open JDK.

Comment: http://jdk.java.net/8/ link is no good, it just shows "The JDK 8 Early Access Program has concluded. Current versions of JDK 8 can be found on www.oracle.com/javadownload"

Comment: I just wanted to mention that the zip file of Android Studio includes OpenJDK8 ;)

Comment: @JaimeOrtega - Just tried that. Maybe it has changed. It seems to be the JRE not the JDK.

Comment: I found openjdk8 for windows on this link http://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/8-MR3

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Go to this [link](http://jdk.java.net/10/)

Download version tar.gz for windows and just extract files to the folder by your needs.
On the left pane, you can select which version of openjdk to download

Tutorial:
unzip as expected. You need to [set system variable PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho) to include your directory with openjdk so you can type java -version in console.

[JDK vs OpenJDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22358071/differences-between-oracle-jdk-and-openjdk)

Comment: But, how can i tell the difference between openjdk and the regular commercial jdk? On the download link http://jdk.java.net/8/ it isnt explicitly stated that its openjdk. Also if i install it and run java -version i cant find anything stating that its openjdk.

Comment: i will edit my post with tutorial

Comment: Sorry, i didnt make my question very clear. If i go to your link, choose jdk8 from left then on that download page there is no mention that its openjdk. If i still go ahead and download that jdk and install it and puth in on system PATH and then run java -version then i get: "Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_112-b15)". How do i know that this is openjdk? It looks just like the commercial oracle jdk.

Comment: Jdk is just fork of openjdk, you will not recognizer it I think

Comment: That site simply contains a link to jdk.java.net. Trying to download from there forces you to log into an Oracle account which requires information like job title and company information which most people will not have.