# How to run R script without opening R or RStudio?

Tags: r

thanks for your time.

I have a more general question, related to a business use case.

I created an R script that takes an excel file, checks certain conditions, and then exports out another excel file.

I created this for a specific use case, and for other people in my organization on a certain team.

The other people in my organization would like to be able to run this R script on their own, without having to contact me every time they want to run it.  They could be running it upwards of a few times a day across the entire team.

On my end, I do not want the team members to have to open up R each time they want to run the script.  It doesn't seem very user friendly from their perspective, and I would prefer to keep the experience easy for them.

So here's my question:  Is there any application I can find or create that the team members can use to run my R script, without having to use R explicitly?

I've done quite a bit of googling around.  One solution I saw was to create an executable version of the file, but I believe that would still be tricky since that would involve customizing each of the team members computers.

I also thought that RShiny might be able to fill the gap?  But I am not familiar with RShiny as of now, and do not know what exactly it can do.

Thanks for any other suggestions you may have.

Comment: Use the `Rscript` executable that runs at command line (cmd, Powershell, Bash, etc.): `Rscript /path/to/my/Rscript.R`. No R app launches or opens in background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are mainly two ways. with using Rscript, like below:

```
C:\Users\automat7> Rscript app.r
```

or in some cases, like with shiny or when running a one line script, usually, you can use

`R -e "shiny::runApp(address_to_folder, args)"`

You may need to add the R's **bin** folder to your PATH environment variable if you are using Windows.
You can follow the instructions here for that: [How to Add a folder to Path environment variable in Windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho)