# Cannot open self C:\Windows\system32\file.exe or archive C:\Windows\system32\file.pkg

Tags: python, cmd, exe, pyinstaller, system32

I try using pyinstaller to convert *.py to *.exe and put them in system32 to try to make them a cmd command but I always get the error:

```
 Cannot open self C:\WINDOWS\system32\file.exe or archive 
    C:\WINDOWS\system32\file.pkg
```

I tried reinstalling pyinstaller and Python and tried different commands and code but nothing works.

I made a dummy file to check if something was wrong with my code

```
print("test")
```

But that didn't work either.
the command I usually use is

```
 pyinstaller --onefile file.py
```

That works great but not if I try using it as a command, I can open it as a file but not a command

I hope I can just type `file` and it executes but now I have to do

```
cd C:\Users\user\Downloads\file.exe
file.exe
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly recommend you do not put your file in System32.

Instead add the path of wherever you keep the .exe file to path.

See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho) for how to add a directory to your path.