# Selenium BOT Error: 'module' object is not callable on webdriver.chrome call

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.chrome("C:\\Users\Ivan\Documents\Python\chromedriver_win32")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
assert "google" in driver.title
```

Python rookie here, i dont get why am i getting 'module' object is not callable, some help will be appreciated thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a typo. `webdriver.chrome` doesn't exist. You'll need to use `webdriver.Chrome` Note the capital C).

Your code, with this correction, will function perfectly fine. Note, however, that assertions are also case-sensitive. The title of the website https://google.com is `Google` and not `google`. By changing the final line of the script to `assert "Google" in driver.title` you will find that it'll run without errors.

ChromeDriver also has its own [reference documentation](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/getting-started), which provides several examples of how to use ChromeDriver with Python and Selenium.

The code below should work fine, though [I recommend adding ChromeDriver to your PATH variables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272417/10595994). This will allow you to simply call `webdriver.Chrome()` rather than having to specify its location.

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\Ivan\Documents\Python\chromedriver_win32")
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
assert "google" in driver.title
```