# Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available even when I installed it

Tags: python, ffmpeg

I am running this command.

```
import bar_chart_race as bcr
bcr.bar_chart_race(df=covid_df,filename=None,figsize=(3.5,3),title='Covid-19 Cases by State',n_bars=10)
```

Getting the below error

```
Exception: You do not have ffmpeg installed on your machine. Download
                            ffmpeg from here: https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html.
                            
                            Matplotlib's original error message below:

                            Requested MovieWriter (ffmpeg) not available
```

Have already installed the module

```
D:\py\Scripts>pip install ffmpeg-python
Requirement already satisfied: ffmpeg-python in d:\py\lib\site-packages (0.1)

D:\py\Scripts>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The ffmpeg-python module and ffmpeg are two different things. You need to install ffmpeg from the link of the error Message

https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html

Comment: I cant download the external applications from my system due to system policies. Is there an alternative way for this ?

Comment: I mean I can download but cant install

Comment: According to `bar_chart_race` you need ffmpeg or magick https://www.dexplo.org/bar_chart_race/installation/.
You can try to find another lib, that uses ffmpeg-python, so far I don`t know any.
Matplotlib has a bit larger variety of video writers you may find there something that works for you.

Comment: @EXODIA you can`t install it since it "only" requires to unzip it and add the bin folder to the path variable?

Answer (score 3):

For those of you who are able to download the ffmpeg file. Here are the steps to activate it.

1. Install the ffmpeg in your cmd using pip or conda:

   ```
   conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg
   ```

   or

   ```
   pip install ffmpeg-python
   ```
2. Download the ffmpeg zip file from the following [link](https://github.com/GyanD/codexffmpeg/releases/tag/2022-03-28-git-5ee198f9aa).

   Since I have Windows OS, I need to put the ffmpeg's bin folder into the path. Unzip the file you've download and copy paste it inside your C: for instance. Put the bin folder to the path using the steps from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho).

Note! After these steps you can check the instalation by runnig this command in your terminal:

```
ffmpeg -version
```

In this case you should not see: 'ffmpeg' is not recognized as an internal or external ecoomand.

For detailed explanation check out this [webpage](https://medium.com/@suryadayn/error-requested-moviewriter-ffmpeg-not-available-easy-fix-9d1890a487d3).

Comment: Was able to get this to work with `brew install ffmpeg` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Run it on COlab it will work
It happened to me on Jupture Only

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).