# Why does python --version return nothing in the command prompt

Tags: python, windows-10

I recently installed Python 3.7.9 for a class I am taking. I am able to run python code both through the windows command prompt and Visual Studio 2019. I was making sure everything was set up correctly. However, when i run the command python --version, it just enters a blank line. IS there something im supposed to do after installing python to set up my Command Prompt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

VS code pulls from the specified file path for each python version, so it will work regardless of if python has been added to your PATH.

Does it give you an error when you just type `python` into your CMD (not inside vs code)?

If it does then you need to add python to your PATH, details for this can be found here:[How to add a folder to `Path` environment variable in Windows 10 (with screenshots)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho)

and the folder paths you need are:

```
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts\
%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\
```

Comment: The command python just sends me to a Microsoft Store page to download Python 3.8. I can still use the command py normally though. I will try what you have suggested.

Comment: @PixelmonMaster ah, I see. Don't use the microsoft store version, it breaks permissions. Download it directly from https://python.org/download and then make sure on the first page of the installer to check off "ADD TO PATH"

Comment: Im not planning on using the store version. I have already installed it.

Comment: I added those folder paths to my environment variable(Picture here https://imgur.com/a/l3DTxqm). It still does not work. I also tried with the %USERPROFILE% still there, but that failed as well.

Comment: @PixelmonMaster I would uninstall the windows store version then and install it from the website. The windows store version is notorious for these sorts of issues. I tried to find out where it saves the installer but I couldn't find the proper details.

Comment: I realized that my last comment regarding the store version wasnt worded well. What I meant to say was that I was not going to install the store version since I already installed 3.7.9 off of the offical python site.

Comment: @PixelmonMaster I see, Try going to ``%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\`` and running ```python.exe --version``` and see if you get the same result. If you do something is off with the installation and I would re-install. If not then check your PATH for other python instances that might be present.

Comment: @PixelmonMaster alternatively you can use the higher layer python windows launcher that should be installed by default I think. You can run ```py --version``` or ```py <file>.py``` instead which should use the latest copy unless specified.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I thought I had left a comment here on Tuesday, but i guess I didn't. When attempting to set the path variables, I noticed my python installation was under Python\Python37-32. After changing it to that things worked perfectly. Sorry for the lack of communication.