# 'meteor' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, meteor

I was starting meteor project and I found this error.

```
'meteor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How can I solve this problem? I am using windows 10 system.

Comment: Can you please add how you installed Meteor? If possible step by step.

Comment: First, I installed Chocolatey.

Comment: and then I run this command
choco install meteor
with PowerShell as administrator.

Comment: Is Meteor under path?

Answer (score 0):

Same message today on fresh `meteor` install on `Windows 10`, `Node 16`, found `meteor` path with a trailing slash in the `PATH` environment variable.

```
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\.meteor/;
```

Removed the trailing slash = `meteor` found.

Answer (score -1):

It's likely you don't have `meteor` in your windows path, and so your shell doesn't know where to find it.

You'll need to add it and then you should be able to use it as usual. Your meteor path should be something like `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor`. If you're not sure how to add it to your PATH, here's a good link which explains it well

[How to add a folder to `Path` environment variable in Windows 10 (with screenshots)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho)

Comment: Also, to troubleshoot, you can try running using the full path,

e.g. `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\.meteor\meteor create simple-todos`