# Sitefinity CLI Upgrade - 12 to 13

Tags: sitefinity

Looks like the upgrade process is now handled by the CLI. Can someone explain the step by step process in a simpler language? Here's the CLI project on Github: https://github.com/Sitefinity/Sitefinity-CLI

Am I supposed to download this and place it in my project folder and then run the command in VS console or in Windows command prompt?

I found this in SF documentations: https://www.progress.com/documentation/sitefinity-cms/upgrade-using-sitefinity-cli

I wish these were written with clearer explanation :(

Comment: I still upgrade directly via Nuget, it's still a valid upgrade procedure.

Comment: I watched this vid: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TPG0XoRTaWY looks like NuGet upgrade is still working. Do you have any idea why some packages should be uninstalled after the NuGet upgrade? Is OpenAccess not required in v 13?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest is to download the latest Cli version from here:
https://github.com/Sitefinity/Sitefinity-CLI/releases

Extract the archive to a folder of your choice and add this folder to the **PATH** system variable.

Then open command prompt where the CLI was extracted and run the following command:

```
sf upgrade "D:\TestProject\SitefinityWebApp.sln" "13.3.7600"
```

Just change the path to point to your solution file.

Comment: Thank you Veselin. Can you please elaborate what you mean by "add this folder to the PATH system variable."?

Comment: I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho  on how to add the folder to the PATH. Running the upgrade now :)