# issue with chromedriver.exe with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, session, path, selenium-chromedriver

I get issues with execution with this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\XXXXX\chromedriver.exe') #Path directory
browser.get('https://www.google.com')
```

The problem is with PATH folder:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of 
ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 101
Current browser version is 100.0.4896.60 with binary path C:\Program 
Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suggest you start reading error messages. It's telling you exactly what the problem is. Chrome Driver and and Chrome versions have to match. See [https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection)

Comment: Now I have a new issue,  Message: 'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home   ----- Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1st issue:

###### Error

`ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 101`

###### Solution

ChromeDriver and Chrome version have to match. Have a look at [the docs](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads/version-selection). So make sure you have matching versions installed.

#### 2nd issue

###### Error

`'C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH`

###### Solution

You need to set [`PATH` variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) to include `C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe` in your operating system i. e. Windows. The `PATH` variables defines the paths that your operating system searches for executables. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho) to see how to set the environment variable in Windows 10. But you can just google for *set `PATH` variable on*  and you will find plenty of tutorials.