# Pyinstaller not recognized after installing

Tags: python, windows, terminal, pip, pyinstaller

I found a similar question, but it didn't match my exact problem. So basically I installed Pyinstaller using `pip install pyinstaller` and I even tried `python -m pip install pyinstaller` (windows terminal pip commands) but then I tried to use it. I just entered `pyinstaller` in the terminal and it told me it was not recognized as an internal or external command. I tried reinstalling it several times but nothing changed. What I'm expecting to happen is for the command to work. Please help. (I am on windows 10 using python 3.9 and pip 22.1.2)

Comment: `pip install pyinstaller` worked? From which env you launched `pyinstaller`?

Comment: You can run command from anywhere if its added to your path. Otherwise provide full path to your pyinstaller

Comment: @NicoCaldo what do you mean

Comment: @NicoCaldo I ran them in my terminal as the other ones

Comment: What editor do you use? You can run `pyinstaller` from python too as documented in https://pyinstaller.org/en/stable/usage.html?highlight=--add-data#running-pyinstaller-from-python-code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your PATH variable doesn't include the path to the `pyinstaller`. You have to add the path to the PATH variable.

Add the following path (Assuming the most common case)

`C:\Users\[USERNAME]\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\[python_folder]\Scripts`

**You have to check whether the path exists and change it accordingly before adding it.**

Find how to add path in windows [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/add-windows-path-environment-variable/)

Comment: @spiceinajar ok, I edited something in the answer

Comment: it appears the exe is already in the directory

Comment: no, it does not. it was already in the directory

Comment: @spiceinajar can you comment your PATH variable

Comment: C:\Users\*******\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts

i still added the directory but the exe was already in the directory before i did that
it still doesnt work

Comment: try `pip show pyinstaller` and check whether is it in PATH

Comment: for some reason it isnt quite...

Comment: @spiceinajar did you mean that `pip show` doesn't show anything

Comment: no, i mean its not where its supposed to be. how do i move it?

Comment: Ah, No need to move it. Just add its current location (current path) to PATH variable

Comment: still broken :/

Comment: try relogging/restarting pc

Comment: nothing. but what confuses me is that its giving me multiple directories when i did [pip sohw]

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Search for your pyinstaller executable. It should be stored somewhere %AppData%\local.

```
>cd C:\Users\username\AppData
>dir /s *pyinstaller*
```

Once you have found it, and the folder it is located in, you may add it to your path.
*(in my example, i found it located at: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts).*

Change your path (temporarly):

```
>set PATH="%PATH%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\"
```

Change your path (permanently):

```
>setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\"
```

Optionnaly:
[This link: How to add (permanently) a folder to a PATH in windows from the GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho)

Comment: i found the exe already in the directory