# RabbitMQ Management is not working because of Could not find handle.exe, please install from sysinternals

Tags: error-handling, rabbitmq

I need your help please.. I installed RabbitMQ server on my windows 10 desktop and then i enabled RabbitMQ management.(e.g **rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management**)

I can see that the rabbit mq plugin is active but when i request to localhost:15672/ it is not working.

When i look at RabbitMQ logs. I get the following error

**Could not find handle.exe, please install from sysinternals**

Thanks.

Comment: How did you originally install RabbitMQ on your Windows 10 desktop? (You _could_ install [`handle.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle) from [Windows SysInternals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/) but really you **should not need to do that** (and I do not know why this would be needed or if it will help). So, I would **not** do that, but instead try to install Rabbit again, correctly. Use [Chocolatey or the system installer](https://www.rabbitmq.com/install-windows.html). Make sure you use an account with admin access to your OS.

Comment: I downloaded (rabbitmq-server-3.10.6.exe) in RabbitMQ web site without chocolatey and then installed. i prefer windows service because i need to stand up as a service. Thinking that this version maybe fault, downgraded this version but nothing changed.

Comment: For what it's worth (a sample of 1): Using Chocolatey will install RabbitMQ as a service on Windows 10. I did not need to install any extra (missing) pieces. I am using v3.10.6.  The management web page is up and running as expected.

Comment: I will try what your said. I will let you know. Thank you

Comment: Problem solved. Cause of the problem, my account name is a Turkish character contains because of that it could not find the path to the RabbitMQ project.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Nice! You are welcome to [answer your own question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: @andrewJames Where exactly would I "install" `handle.exe`? The download from sysinternals is just a zip of executables. (fyi chocolatey is not an option)

Comment: @marsze - Two options: (A) Once you have the unzipped directory of all these tools (exes) you can [add that directory to your path](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44272416/12567365). (B) There is a newer way (which I have not tried) - using **Sysinternals Suite**: Go to the [Microsoft store](https://apps.microsoft.com/store) and search for Sysinternals Suite. Apparently if you install that directly from the store, then you get updates automatically. It will be listed in the Start menu. TEST to ensure it is installed: Open a command prompt and type `handle /?` to see the help page.