# Reg : How to Download YT playlist and convert them compressed Audio file using Python?

Tags: python

[image]Can someone please help me in Downloading a Playlist from YT and compressing them into Audio file please.. I tried with below shown code..

```
from pytube import YouTube
from pytube import Playlist
from pydub import AudioSegment
import os
import moviepy.editor as mp
import re

YOUTUBE_STREAM_AUDIO = '140' # modify the value to download a different stream
DOWNLOAD_DIR = 'C:\\MyData\\NewAudio'

playlist = Playlist("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9bZufPHFLU&list=PLfqMhTWNBTe0b2nM6JHVCnAkhQRGiZMSJ")

# this fixes the empty playlist.videos list
#playlist._video_regex = re.compile(r"\"url\":\"(/watch\?v=[\w-]*)")

print(len(playlist.video_urls))

for url in playlist.video_urls:
    print(url)

# physically downloading the audio track
for video in playlist.videos:
    audioStream = video.streams.get_by_itag(YOUTUBE_STREAM_AUDIO)
    audioStream.download(output_path=DOWNLOAD_DIR)

    for file in os.listdir(DOWNLOAD_DIR):
        if re.search('mp4', file):
            mp4_path = os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_DIR, file)
            mp3_path = os.path.join(DOWNLOAD_DIR, os.path.splitext(file)[0] + '.mp3')
            new_file = mp.AudioFileClip(mp4_path)
            new_file.write_audiofile(mp3_path)

            os.remove(mp4_path)
```

Comment: Is something wrong with your attempt?

Comment: As attached, while running the code, I'm getting error as shown. Also, the code printing each playlist link in console window.

Comment: Post errors (and other codes) as text instead of screenshots so they can be copyable/searchable.

Comment: There is no errors on your code, it's just a bunch of warnings !!

Comment: But, the playlist is not converting into MP3 Audio files :-(

Answer (score 0):

If those warnings are preventing your code to function properly... You'll want to install FFMPEG by either:

- Placing `ffmpeg.exe` in your project's directory
- Putting `ffmpeg.exe` [into PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44272416/how-to-add-a-folder-to-path-environment-variable-in-windows-10-with-screensho)

You can find downloads for FFMPEG [here](https://ffmpeg.org/download.html), and you can find the `ffmpeg.exe` in the `bin` folder of the `.zip`/`.7z` file downloaded from there.