# How to extract .000 file type in python

Tags: python-3.x, 7zip, shutil

How to extract them in python scripts by using shutil or somethings

[image]

```
import os
import shutil

directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "BDP Raw data")

def extract(path,director,check):
    if check:
        shutil.unpack_archive(path, directory)
    if check == False:
        shutil.unpack_archive(path, directory,'tar')
def extractzip():
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if file.endswith('.zip'):
            file_path = f"{directory}\{file}"
            extract(file_path,directory,True)
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if file.startswith('9050') or file.startswith('9070'):
            directory_path = f"{directory}\{file}"
            for file in os.listdir(directory_path):
                extractTo000 = f"{directory}\TestExtract000"
                extract_path000 = f"{directory_path}\{file}"
                extract(extract_path000,extractTo000,False)
extractzip()
```

Output should be like this method :

[image]

Then I must get this:

[image]

Comment: extrack look like "shutil.unpack_archive(path_file, extract_to)" in python

Comment: `.000 file` seems to be just a text file. Please add your code and expected output.

Comment: ok i put it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that [**`shutil`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) or even [**`py7zr`**](https://pypi.org/project/py7zr/) would be able to extract a `.000` file.

One of the workarounds is to use Python's built-in module [**`subprocess`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) to unzip this kind of files by 7zip through the Windows command line.

##### 1- CONFIGURATING THE VARIABLE ENVIRONNEMENT

First of all, you need to execute the command below in the command prompt to make sure that your user path environement is pointing to the .exe file of `7-zip`. You can also do that manually (see this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44272417/19603419)).

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\"
```

##### 2- WRITING THE PYTHON FILE

Then, create a `.py` file in the same directory of your `.000` files and write the code below :

```
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess

path = r'C:\Users\abokey\Desktop\000files'

for file in Path(path).glob('*.000'):
    print(file)
    subprocess.call(['7z', 'e', file], shell=True)
```

[image]

If you need to extract the files to a specific directory, add the option -o (Set Output Directory):

```
#make sure to change the output path
subprocess.call(['7z', 'e', file, r'-oC:\Users\abokey\Desktop\000files\output'], shell=True)
```

Make sure to adapt the code below to match your expectations :

```
from pathlib import Path
import os
import subprocess

directory = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "BDP Raw data")

extractTo000 = directory + r'\TestExtract000'

for file in Path(directory).glob('*.000'):
    if file.stem.startswith(('9050', '9070')):
     subprocess.call(['7z', 'e', file, fr'-o{extractTo000}'], shell=True)
```

**Note** : *Read full documentation of 7zip [**here**](https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/commands/extract.htm).*